# Contentful - Next.js Versioning Issue Error 409

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, contentful, contentful-management

I'm trying to update an existing entry in Contentful with [the Contentful Management API](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/).

In Contentful, every entry included a `views` field which represents a views counter. I want to increase that counter every time the page is reloaded. But I'm running into a `versionMismatch` error.

[VersionMismatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URpkD.png)

Here's the source code:

```
const [ViewsCounter, setViewsCounter] = useState(views);

useEffect(() => {
  client
    .getSpace("------")
    .then((space) => space.getEnvironment("master"))
    .then((environment) => environment.getEntry(PostId))
    .then((entry) => {
      entry.fields.views["en-US"] = ViewsCounter;
      return entry.update();
    })
    .then((entry) => entry.publish())
    .catch(console.error);
}, [ViewsCounter]);

useEffect(() => {
  setViewsCounter((prev) => (prev += 1));
}, []);
```

Comment: are you using a session to store the data between the reloads?

Comment: No, the default value for views is pulled from Contentful and only what I need is  update that value

Comment: I don't think you need to publish the entry after the update. Try removing the `.then((entry) => entry.publish())` line.

Comment: I tried both solutions, but have the same issue